# Expected exception is not thrown, when DataView.RowFilter is set to incorrect filter

Tags: c#, .net, exception, system.data

I use `System.Data.DataView.RowFilter` for table filtration. I have a column "Time" with `DateTime` datatype and for this column I use following filter:

> Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03.000'

But accidently I mistyped dot that separates seconds and milliseconds and instead typed in semicolon:

> Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03:000'.

I had some data in table and in first case it was filtered as it should be, but second case gave empty result.

But when I tried to recreate this problem outside of the project, I found out, that second case throws exception!

Code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var col = dt.Columns.Add("Time");
col.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["Time"] = DateTime.Parse("14.12.2015 11:38:03.000");
dt.Rows.Add(row);
dt.Rows.Count.Dump();
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter="Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03.000'"; // Ok.
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter="Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03:000'"; // Evaluation Exception.
```

I've checked several times and in my project:

- This exception is not thrown.
- RowFilter is equal to `"Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03:000'"` after assingment.
- Code execution is continued as it does when correct filter expression is used.

I thought that it might be .Net 4.0 bug and set my test app's framework to it. 
Same result: it throws exception, but no exception in project.

In test app exception is thrown even without debugging, in release build, so it's not dependent on debugger settings.

I've double checked that I use same classes from same library.

I run both my project and test app on same PC.

Here is debug screenshot with next step after `RowFilter` value was set to incorrect filter and it accept it without exception:
[image: Incorrect filtes is successfuly set.]

**What can be cause for this situation when expected exception is not raised?**

Comment: are you sure there are no `try...catch` blocks higher up in the program that are catching the exception?

Comment: @Matthew yes, there is, but it doesn't matter. Look at screenshot, execution steped to next line and applied filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested your code and it seems that the filter is not tested unless there is a row in the datatable 
this code works

```
var dt = new DataTable();
            var col = dt.Columns.Add("Time");
            col.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            //var row = dt.NewRow();
            //row["Time"] = DateTime.Parse("14.12.2015 11:38:03.000");
            //dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03.000'"; 
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Time<= '15.12.2015 11:38:03:000'";
```

but if you add a row in the datatable after setting the filter it will generate an error saying you can't compare a Time with String

```
 var row = dt.NewRow();
 row["Time"] = DateTime.Parse("14.12.2015 11:38:03.000");
 dt.Rows.Add(row); //this will generate an error
```

**Error “Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.”**

so the filter is not executed when the datatable is empty

EDIT : 
CodingFeles : in order for filter to be tested, table should have some values in columns that used in the filter

Comment: Thank you! Funny, in my project row is added too. I decided to hide some parts of code from screenshot and removed adding empty row before setting filter and even with row it didn't throw exception. But it really is the case and you're right! My row was empty, and after I set `Time` value as you did, exception was thrown. Also, I tested case, when `Time` is empty and another column is set - exception is not thrown. So, in order for filter to be tested, table should have some values in columns that used in the filter. I suggest that you update your answer with this info.